Correct way to downgrade subscriptions at the end of billing cycle in Stripe
I'm using Stripe for the first time. I want to set up downgrades that take effect only after the current billing period.
First, I tried this:
(Spoiler: It didn't work - The subscription was downgraded immediately)
await stripe.subscriptions.update(user.stripeSubscriptionId, {
          items: [{
            id: currentSubscription.items.data[0].id,
            price: prod_env,
          }],
          proration_behavior: 'none',
          cancel_at_period_end: true,
          metadata: {
            plan: productName,
            userId: userId.toString(),
          },
        });

        await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({
          customer: user.stripeCustomerId,
          start_date: currentSubscription.current_period_end,
          phases: [
            {
              items: [
                {
                  price: prod_env,
                  quantity: 1,
                },
              ],
              metadata: {
                plan: productName,
                userId: userId.toString(),
              }
            },
          ],
        });

Then, I tried this:
await stripe.subscriptions.update(user.stripeSubscriptionId, {
          items: [{
            id: currentSubscription.items.data[0].id,
            price: prod_env,
          }],
          proration_behavior: 'none',
          metadata: {
            current_plan: currentPlan,
            scheduled_plan: productName,
            userId: userId.toString(),
          },
          cancel_at_period_end: true
        });

This doesn't downgrade the plan immediately, but I'm not sure if it will cancel the plan entirely at the end of the billing period or not. Can you confirm if this is the correct approach? I read the Prorations and Upgrading/Downgrading sections, but I couldn't find a direct reference to this method.
Any help is appreciated. Have a great day!

Setting cancel_at_period_end will cancel the entire Subscription at the end of the current period, which isn't want you want.
If you want to schedule a change to a Subscription ahead of time Stripe provides Subscription Schedules for that purpose.  They even have a downgrade subscriptions use case documented which closely matches what you want to do.
Also note that Stripe has test clocks which let you advance time in test mode, so you don't have to wait days/weeks/months to see and test changes over time.

Hey Justin,
Thanks for the response. Your tip was handy.
This is what I implemented:
await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({
          customer: user.stripeCustomerId,
          start_date: currentSubscription.current_period_end,
          end_behavior: 'release',
          phases: [
            {
              items: [
                {
                  price: prod_env,
                  quantity: 1,
                }
              ],
            }
          ],
        });

This works, but should I use from_subscription here instead?

If you want to create a Subscription Schedule for an existing Subscription you would use from_subscription to specify the existing Subscription, yep.  The API reference explains it a bit more.
